# How to add keywords (syntax highlighting) to general syntax highlighter or language extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to add specific keywords that I would like highlighted the same as keywords.
E.g. having u8 highlighted the same colour as int or float.

Answer (score 0):

To what language are you wanting?

You can modify extensions you have installed by going to
Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`
macOS: `~/.vscode/extensions`
Linux: `~/.vscode/extensions`

Depending on the lanuage, it can be as easy as just adding your keywords to the list inside a rule